# Python - temporary loggers for selective in-memory logging

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I have some Python code which writes some logs (using the standard `logging` module). In most cases, I want the logs to simply propagate to upper-level loggers, but sometimes I need to also write the logs to an in-memory stream (e.g. a `StringIO`) for later retrieval.

I have thought of two approaches to this:

a) Create a new temporary logger instance with a unique name for each run of the code. If needed, attach an additional handler to that logger for my in-memory logging.
The problem here is that, since there is no way of removing loggers in Python, I get an inevitable memory leak.

b) Make a wrapper function for logging that calls `logger.log` and, if needed, also performs the in-memory logging.
The problem here is that I lose the information about filename and line number at which the logging was performed, as the `logging` module thinks that it was called from the wrapper.

What would be the best workaround for this problem?

If that makes any difference in this case, I am using Python 2.7.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What I have done in the past, and I'm not saying this is the right way to do it, is create a logging function which deletes all handlers as one of the first actions. Afterwards it follows a serious of `try` and `except` statements within which are the situational logging handlers that log the different levels of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to avoid the memory leak in the first approach. The key to it is to create the loggers manually by instantiating the `Logger` class instead of calling `logging.getLogger`. This way the temporary loggers are not registered in the centralized registry and thus can be garbage collected.

Comment: Python documentation says "Note that Loggers should NEVER be instantiated directly, but always through the module-level function logging.getLogger(name). Multiple calls to getLogger() with the same name will always return a reference to the same Logger object." though I agree with you that there are valid use-cases in which not to use the getLogger API.